# How to match a class with type parameters using mock?

Tags: mockito

For example,

```
verify(conversationService).addState(any(ID.class));
```

Here the parameter required by `addState` is of type: `ID<Document>`, how do I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Matchers` class to achieve what you want:

```
verify(conversationService).addState(Matchers.<ID<Document>>any());
```